# Error in prototyping Javascript "Class" - not a function and undefined variable

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I am writing a Javascript class to cycle through a number of ticks and call a function at specified ticks.  However, I am having a problem with my prototyping of the Javascript Class.  The main count variable appears as undefined or Nan and one of the functions (methods) is apparently "not a function".  Am just perplexed. Any pointers would be great.

Here is a JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/hp5dj665/ but here is the code in question:

```
<script>
function tickStep(tickInMilliSeconds){
        this.tickCount = 0; //just used as a counter
        this.tickMax = 48; //highest number of ticks before it ends
        this.monitorTextInputId = "";
        this.paused = false;
        this.tickMilliSeconds = tickInMilliSeconds;
        this.tickRepeat = true; //when reaching the end start again at the beginning
        this.eventArray = new Array();
        this.setint; //the set time out variable      
    }

    tickStep.prototype = {
        constructor: tickStep,

        monitorTick:function(){
            console.log(this.tickCount);
        /*  if(this.monitorTextInputId.length>0){
                document.getElementById(this.monitorTextInputId).value = this.tickCount;
            }*/
        },

        tick:function(){
            if(!this.paused){                   
                console.log("HERE: "+this.tickCount); // WHY IS THIS NaN ??? <---------------
                this.tickCount++;
                if(this.tickCount>this.tickMax && this.tickRepeat){
                    this.tickCount = 0;
                }
                 console.log("tick: "+this.tickCount);
                if(this.tickCount>this.tickMax && !this.tickRepeat){
                    this.stop();
                    return false;
                }
                this.monitorTick(); // <!----------------- WHY DOES THIS SAY IT IS NOT A FUNCTION?
                if(typeof this.eventArray[this.tickCount] !== "undefined"){
                    if(this.isAFunction(this.eventArray[this.tickCount])){
                        eval(this.eventArray[this.tickCount]);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                console.log("Paused...");
            }
        },

        isAFunction:function(functionalCall){
            if(functionName.indexOf("(")){ //remove the brackety stuff
                functionName = functionName.substring( 0,functionName.indexOf("(") );                   
            }
            console.log("Testing for function: "+functionName);
            return typeof(functionName) === typeOf(Function);
        },

        start:function(){
            console.log("STARTING");
            if(!this.tickMilliSeconds>0){
                this.tickMilliSeconds = 1000; //default to 1 second
                console.log("defaulting to 1 tick = 1000ms")
            }
            console.log("Tick duration: "+this.tickMilliSeconds);
            this.setint = window.setInterval(this.tick,this.tickMilliSeconds);
        },

        stop:function(){
            console.log("STOPPING");        
            clearInterval(this.setint);
        },

        restart:function(){
            console.log("RESTARTING");
            this.stop();
            this.tickCount =0;
            this.start();
        },

        pause:function(){
            this.paused = !this.paused;
        },

        addEvent:function(tickValue,funcCall,params){
            this.eventArray[this.tickValue] = funcCall+"("+params+")";
        },

        removeEvent:function(tickValue){
            this.eventArray[this.tickValue] = null; 
        }

    } //end of tickStep prototype



    var seq = new tickStep();
    seq.monitorTextInputId = "tb";

    var myFunction = function(){
        console.log("myFunctionCalled");
    }

    seq.addEvent(2,myFunction,"");
  seq.start();

</script>
```

So
1.  Why does the "this.tickCount" == Nan or undefined inside the Tick function 
2.  Why is this.monitorTick()  apparently not a function when this.tick() is a function?

Stuff may break after that as I can't get past that stage - but I would like those two queries sorted out so I can progress. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Just for completeness sake, following a couple of the comments I thought I would post that the addEvent function is now:

```
        addEvent:function(tickValue,funcCall,params){
            this.eventArray[tickValue] = Array(funcCall,params);                
        },
```

and tick is now:

```
     tick:function(){
            if(!this.paused){                   
                this.tickCount++;
                if(this.tickCount>this.tickMax && this.tickRepeat){
                    this.tickCount = 0;
                }
                if(this.tickCount>this.tickMax && !this.tickRepeat){
                    this.stop();
                    return false;
                }
                this.monitorTick();
                if(typeof this.eventArray[this.tickCount] != "undefined"){
                    this.eventArray[this.tickCount][0](this.eventArray[this.tickCount][1]);
                }
            }else{
                console.log("Paused...");
            }
        },
```

Binding "this" on the setInterval call solved the initial problem. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Everything about handling function parameters in that code is pretty much wrong. It's hard to know where to even start.

Comment: Well I am trying to transfer from a flat script to an object for neatness, based on various examples round the web, including this one:  http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: @Pointy, why is everytying about handling function parameters wrong?

Comment: When you pass a reference to a function as a parameter - `seq.addEvent(2, myFunction, "")` - you're passing a reference to the function object, not a name. You cannot associate it with parameters by concatenating a string onto that reference. You cannot test to see if a reference is a reference to a function by looking at it as a string.

Comment: right oh, I have since modified that bit.  Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess because the `tick` function is called by `setInterval` and is therefore not bound to the object. Try

```
this.setint = window.setInterval(this.tick.bind(this),this.tickMilliSeconds);
```

Read more about the meaning of `this` in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: right so "this" doesn't explicity refer to the current object?

Comment: When the script was flat (before I started making it into an object) the principle worked.  Testing now.

Comment: "*not bound to the object anymore*" - it's not exactly like it was ever bound to an object.

Comment: Yes you are right. It's just that words elude me on how to describe it eloquently.

Comment: I am used to "this" in the context of PHP, guess I throw that out the window here.

Comment: Look at it like this: you define the function on the object's prototype, but the function is still just a function. When you call it on the object directly, the `this` keyword will be set to the object. When you pass it around as a pointer it will be called directly, not on the object, and so the `this` keyword will not be set. If you read the answer to the question yours is a duplicate to you'll get it, it's very well answered!

Comment: Yes I have read that now, and it does kind of make sense. Reading around, there are various articles saying to do things like setting "var self = this"  inside the constructor.  However, if it is a var then one cannot access that through the other method-functions.  Anyhow the bind does the job.   Not really written any "objects" in JS.  Had written the script flat and thought I would be neat.  Kind of backfired :)

Comment: Pointy said "Everything about handling function parameters in that code is pretty much wrong."  Is that really the case?

Comment: He was probably referring to how you handle dynamic function calling, the adding and invoking part of it to be specific. You should NEVER use `eval`, you can easily do what you're doing by using `bind`, `apply` or `call` on the callbacks. Keep learning!

Comment: cheers for that, will look at alternative.